# My reputation number seems to be misaligned in the top right profile info bar

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, google-chrome

I am unsure if this is just me, but my reputation number seems to be misaligned. It is only on the Stack Overflow sites, as far as I know. (Tested on Academia and Workplace) I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome. I could not reproduce on Mozilla. I also tested in incognito mode and still got the same issue. In addition, I am not using any custom scripts or anything like that. I might be wrong but it looks to be slightly above center, and it is stressing me out seeing it.

[image]

Comment: Now I can't *un*see it.

Comment: @Makoto Welcome to the club! Are you also on Linux?

Comment: Looks like everything's top-aligned, and the score's font is smaller than the one used for the badge counts. Or rather, the browser is rendering them differently; the code seems to indicate they are the same size.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when browsing SO in Firefox 61.0.1, on Windows 7.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Chrome 66 on Debian/Gnome.

Comment: Take a break from SO if this is causing you undue stress. If *that* causes you undue stress, then you may be addicted.

Comment: Can't produce on maxOS High Sierra 10.13.4 Safari 11.1

Comment: No repro on Windows 7, Chrome.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think it's the badge icons.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 67, Windows 10 17134.112.

Comment: Can’t reproduce it on Firefox Nightly 63.0a1 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Are you zoomed out (or not at 100% zoom) by any chance?

Comment: Confirming no repro on 18.04 / Firefox.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Its 100% zoom

Comment: Can reproduce on Ubuntu 14.04 Chrome

Comment: Can't repro on Linux with Chromium Version 66.0.3359.181

Comment: If you inspect the element, what does the Font pane reveal? Any weird font files installed on your system?

Comment: No repro: FF61.0 on macOS HS 10.13.4 zoom 100%

Comment: No repro on the latest Chrome / Win 10. Sounds like a browser / OS issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 67.0.3396.99, MacOS 10.13.5

Comment: @Xufox does not seem to be any weird font files

Comment: Any updates, I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Font looks pretty clearly wrong to me; can't imagine why, but thinking this is some oddity specific to Ubuntu; I've tagged accordingly as Sheshank confirmed seeing this as well.

Comment: Firefox 61.0 and Chromium 67.0.3396.87-1 in Debian testing, no repro

Comment: Is this still an issue? We've made a lot of style changes since this was filed and I'm checking in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in the last topbar cleanup we did for responsive design.